# Null Pointer Exception on Custom ListView Item

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, seekbar

Ok so:
I have a ListView with custom adapter. In ListView Item I have a SeekBar.
ListView adapter is in different class, and I want to when I click on listview to play some sound and show it on SeekBar(Like a progress bar).

The Problem:
I get null pointer exception because the SeekBar is in different Layout. The Listview item Layout.

Question:
How can I or what I need to do to *link* SeekBar with Main Activity?

I didn't add any code because it's pretty simple adapter I need an idea to do this.

Comment: `SeekBar` is in Activity or in Adapter ?

Comment: Paste your list items and activity layouts, and adapter and activity codes.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK It's in adapter.

Comment: Then paste the layout for items and adapter code.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the SeekBar in the same layout as your listView row. You can set the visibility of SeekBar to invisible/visible/gone depending on your need.

Comment: SeekBar is already invisible. When sound is played on lets say item 3, Seekbar on Item 3 is Visible. Others remain invisible.